# Alguna funcion jquery para controlar un input solo se escriban numeros?

Tags: html, jquery

Alguna funcion jquery para controlar un input solo se escriban numeros que lo acepten todos los navegadores y que tambien acepte enter, borrar y tab?

Comment: y cuando quieres agregar el punto decimal como seria la expresión

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usando `jQuery` puede hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-number" value="" />
```

Comment: +1 por el snippet

Comment: y esta muy bien :D sencillo y practico.. quiza solo agregar una advertencia donde diga que solo se pueden escribir numeros :D

Answer (score 2):

Crea una funcion JavaScript como la siguiente

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
      $('.solo-numero').keyup(function (){
        this.value = (this.value + '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      });
    });
</script>
```

Y finalmente llamarias esa funcion en tu elemento html

```
<input type="text" value="" class="solo-numero">
```

Comment: Ya habia usado esta funcion pero el input esta inicializado en 0 y cuando escribo a la primer escribe 01 y no 1 tengo que borrar primero y luego borrar

Comment: Bastaría con añadir dentro de la función un `if (this.value == '0') { this.value = '';}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

o también

```
<input type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar:

```html
<input type="number" name="campo_numerico" />
```

Comment: creo que la pregunta consulta claramente por una función jquery, aunque tu respuesta también realiza lo que se pide

Comment: En cuanto a validación cumple, pero no **impide** que se pueda **escribir** carácteres diferentes a números.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he usado jquery Autonumeric:
[autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) y también una función: ForceNumericOnly, anexo el código para que te des una idea.  Saludos.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.demo').autoNumeric('init');
  $(".soloNumero").ForceNumericOnly();
});

jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
  function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).keydown(function(e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
        // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
        return (
          key == 8 ||
          key == 9 ||
          key == 46 ||
          (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
          (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
          (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
      });
    });
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/autoNumeric-1.9.41.js"></script>
<h2>Con AutoNumeric</h2>
<br/>
Con minimos y maximos
<br/>
<input type="text" name="demoMinMax" id="demoMinMax" class="demo" data-v-min="-99999999999" data-v-max="0" data-a-sep=" " data-m-dec="2" data-w-empty="zero" value="">
<br/>Default
<br/>
<input type="text" name="demoDefaults" id="demoDefaults" class="demo">
<br/>
<h2>Con Funcion ForceNumericOnly</h2>
<br/>Funcion de jquery
<br/>
<input type="text" class="soloNumero" id="demoFuncion">
```